# Why isnt jQuery Fittext working?

Tags: jquery, html

Cant seem to get it work. This is what I have so far. It all seems to load properly but it doesnt respond to the browser.

HTML

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".fancy_title").lettering();
            });
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery("#responsive_headline").fitText();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<section id="responsive_headline" class="fancy_title">September</section>
```

CSS

```
#responsive_headline {
    font-size: 220px;
    font-family: "utopia-std",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

You can view it live [here](http://septemberstudio.co.uk/)

Comment: What browser are you using? This works perfectly on Mozilla FF, Google Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to ensure the:

```
<script>
   jQuery("#responsive_headline").fitText();
</script>
```

is after the div or target. Then remove the `font-size`in your CSS. Text is made bigger like so:

```
<script>
   jQuery("#responsive_headline").fitText(.8);
</script>
```